# Building gcc 4.8.4 from source: cp-cilkplus.o no such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora, gcc4.8

I try to build GCC 4.8.4 from source under Fedora 25. I have already GCC 6.4.1.
I have installed Bison, Flex, GMP, MPFR, MPC.

The following configuration is used:

```
configure --prefix /home/installations/gcc48 --enable-languages=c,c++ \
--disable-multilib --enable-threads=posix --disable-nls \
--disable-bootstrap --disable-checking --enable-multiarch \
--enable-shared --program-suffix=4.8 --with-system-zlib \
--with-tune=generic --without-included-gettext
```

But, when I run

```
make -j4
```

I get this error:

```
opening cp/cp-cilkplus.o: No such file or directory
../../gcc-4.8.4/gcc/cp/Make-lang.in:95: recipe for target 'cc1plus-checksum.c' failed
make[2]: *** [cc1plus-checksum.c] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Making symbolic directory links
Fixing directory /usr/include into /home/installations/objdir/gcc/include-fixed
........
Cleaning up unneeded directories:
fixincludes is done
echo timestamp > stmp-fixinc
rm gcc.pod
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/installations/gcc48/gcc'
Makefile:3920: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/installations/gcc48'
Makefile:864: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is wrong? What should I check?